# how to paste texttocolumns from a file to excel using vb.net from right side of columns

Tags: vb.net

i have a problem while copy from a file and paste in the excel using vb.net.
while using texttocolumns in vb.net in excel it paste like this starting from the left column
for example:

```
3   12       2      1073.91 -0.1     1.7     0.02   -5.14   -0.5
14 -1067.73  0.1     -1.7   -0.02   1.74     0.29       
13  2       787.99  16.39   2.16    -0.12   -4.22   21.28
```

My data has 9, 7 and 8 columns in each rows respectively.  when i using texttocolumns in vb.net it is pasting 3,14 & 13 in one columns. but i want to pate from right side columns.ie

```
3   12  2   1073.91 -0.1    1.7   0.02  -5.14   -0.5
       14  -1067.73  0.1   -1.7  -0.02   1.74    0.29
    13  2   787.99  16.39   2.16 -0.12  -4.22   21.28
```

how to do this. please help me

i used the following syntax in the program:

.columns(1).TextToColumns( _
            Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            DataType:=Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
            Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, _
            Comma:=False, _
            Space:=True, _
            Other:=False, _
            TrailingMinusNumbers:=False)

gvg

Comment: Use TAB as your column delimiter.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include right-alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a file named `test.txt` containing the following:

```
3   12  2   1073.91 -0.1    1.7 0.02    -5.14   -0.5
14  -1067.73    0.1 -1.7    -0.02   1.74    0.29
13  2   787.99  16.39   2.16    -0.12   -4.22
```

This is one way of doing it in vb.net:

```
Dim text As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")

Me.TextBox1.Text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, " {2,}", " ").Replace(" ", vbTab)

'Or:

My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, " {2,}", " ").Replace(" ", vbTab))
```

**Edit**

This will right-align all values:

```
Dim text As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\test.txt")
Dim lines As String() = text.Trim().Split(vbNewLine)
Dim item As String = Nothing
Dim num As Integer = 0

For i As Integer = (lines.Length - 1) To 0 Step -1
    item = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(lines(i), " {2,}", " ").Trim()
    num = (8 - (item.Length - item.Replace(" ", "").Length))
    lines(i) = (New String(vbTab, num) & item.Replace(" ", vbTab))
Next

Me.TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, lines)

'Or:

My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, " {2,}", " ").Replace(" ", vbTab))
```

Comment: thank you roger for you reply. i do not know how many lines are there in the file. i think you have given for only three lines of text. if many lines are there in the file, how to do this. please help me.

Comment: @user3060904 The content of `text` was just an example. Just read the file into the `text` variable. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i am copying certain text in between lines from a file to excel and splitting using texttocolumns as my earlier post ( using start and stop mark). The code you provided me that was not worked for my problem. please help me.